# Windows Phone 8.0 control app image when in background

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a way to control what the WP8.0 app screen looks like when in background task. I mean when cycling over the apps after a long press on back button ?

I'm using a custom Prism, and I tried to set a different background from OnNavigatedFrom but it seems that the page is already unbound at this moment because this has no effect on the page.